# How to clip a plot but still show the plot's node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I wanted to create a template as I usually reuse some code to make new task sheets etc. The problem I am running into from time to time and then manually fix, is that I clip away my labels of my functions. I usually add a custom placed node where I want the description afterwards. Is there a more elegant solution to do this?

I usually run into problems if I not crop my plot, as the domain only specifies x coordinates and the y coordinates tend to leave the grid rather easily.

The code I currently use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ cross/.style={draw, cross out,
        minimum size=2*(#1-1pt), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}, x=1cm, y=1cm]
    %----------------
    %Grid
    \draw [color=gray!50]  [step=5mm] (-2,-2) grid (11,11);
    %----------------
    % Axis
    \draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0) -- (11,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->,thick] (0,-1.5) -- (0,11) node[above] {$y$};
    %----------------
    \foreach \x in {-1,1,2,...,10}
    \draw (\x,-.1) -- (\x,.1) node[below=4pt] {$\scriptstyle\x$};
    \foreach \y in {-1,1,2,...,10}
    \draw (-.1,\y) -- (.1,\y) node[left=4pt] {$\scriptstyle\y$};
    %----------------
    %Functions:
    %----------------
    \clip (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (10.5,10.5);
    %----
    \draw[smooth, domain=-1:6] plot (\x, {2*pow(\x-3,2)-1}) node[right] {$f(x)=x$};          
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of the node, define a coordinate `coordinate (placeforthenode)` and put both both the `\clip` and the `\draw … plot` in a `scope` environment. And after the `scope` environment, you can say `\node[right] at (placeforthenode) {$f(x)=x$};`. However, that would be far away from your drawn area. I'd do `\node[right]at (6, 10.5) {$f(x)=x$};`. (You will still need the `scope` environment.)

Comment: Are you aware of the [tag:pgfplots] package?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I am, but I have had trouble getting pgfplots to work in a way, so that printed graphics constructed with it have a grid size of 0.5 cm. That is just the norm paper students use. As they sometimes need to measure and such, I need the grid to fit this restriction.

Comment: @curies to have exact size on the axis (and so the grids) you probably need the option `scale only axis` --- then you can set the axis length and the tics so that you have the 0.5 cm grid.

Comment: Hi @curies!  I don't understand your problem.  I have the pdf result of your file (by the way, you must insert a `\begin{document}`).  It is a parabola on a coordinate axes enhanced with a grid.  What do you want to clip?  What do you want to add as a node?